# JavaScript export / import doesn't work

Tags: javascript, module, export

it might be a silly question but I can't fix it anyway. I have a JavaScript file with various functions I'd like to export.

```
export function AddNumbers(...numbers)
{
    let value = 0;

    for(var i = 0;i < numbers.length;i++)
    {
        value += numbers[i];
    }

    return value;
}
```

When I call this method (using mocha) I get an error message "*export* function AddNumbers(...numbers) Unexpected token export". The project is build as ES6. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Best regards,
Torsten

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `module.exports` as NodeJS uses CommonJS Module syntax which requires to use `module.exports` and not just `export` which is defined by ES6 module syntax. So, make sure `CommonJS` is also configured properly in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use Babel. Install it with

```
npm install babel-core --save-dev
npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev
```

Create in root directory a file .babelrc with following content

```
{
    "preset" : ["es2015"]
}
```

and finally change the script in package.json to run into:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha Tests --require babel-core/register"
}
```

and now export / import works.