# The import and export method doesn't work in js file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to import a function in my js file. Here is a simple code:

```js
// In index.js file
function addition(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

export { addition };

// In test.js file

import { addition } from "./index.js";

console.log(addition(5, 4));
```

The result in the console:
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: The error message flat out tells you two different solutions to this problem!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript export / import doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618332/javascript-export-import-doesnt-work)

Comment: Yes @Phoenix1355!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NodeJS uses CommonJS Module syntax which doesn't support `import/export`, but instead requires to use `module.exports` like so:

```js
// In index.js file
function addition(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

module.exports = addition;

// In test.js file

const addition = require("./index.js");

console.log(addition(5, 4));
```

Comment: "NodeJS uses CommonJS Module syntax" — Only by default. It supports ES6 modules and the error message explains how to use them.

Comment: @Quentin, it indeed does, but it seems like he runs Node directly on the javascript file, and from that, I assume he isn't using an NPM project at all with a package.json, which is required for the solution suggested in the error to work.

Comment: I will mark your question as better question.

Comment: @Phoenix1355 — There's no evidence in the question, one way or other, about the existence of a `package.json` file. It's required for *one* of the two solutions in the error to work. It could be created if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

To use the modern import/export syntax with NodeJS you have to set your package type to `module` in the package.json file, like you are told in the console output.

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs